# XML serializing return null

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I would like to obtain the information (Name and Val) inside the "U8" node of the following XML string that I got from a text file.

```
<Cluster>   
    <String>
        <Name>SomeNAme</Name>
        <Val>
            &lt;Cluster&gt;
                &lt;Name&gt;SomeNAme&lt;/Name&gt;
                &lt;NumElts&gt;2&lt;/NumElts&gt;
                &lt;U8&gt;
                    &lt;Name&gt;SomeNAme&lt;/Name&gt;
                    &lt;Val&gt;11&lt;/Val&gt;
                &lt;/U8&gt;
                &lt;U8&gt;
                    &lt;Name&gt;SomeNAme&lt;/Name&gt;
                    &lt;Val&gt;208&lt;/Val&gt;
                &lt;/U8&gt;
            &lt;/Cluster&gt;
        </Val>
    </String>
</Cluster>
```

I wrote the following to obtain the information belong to the U8 node but the output return Null. What did I do wrong? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
namespace testXMLSerializer
{
    class Class4
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.xml");

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cluster));

            using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                var info = (Cluster)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Cluster")]
    public class Cluster
    {
        [XmlElement("String")]
        public List<Cluster_String> Cluster_String { get; set; } // I'll have many of this items in the actual xml
    }

    public class Cluster_String
    {
        [XmlElement("Val")]
        public Val Val { get; set; }
    }

    public class Val
    {
        [XmlElement("Cluster")]
        public Cluster_S_V_Cluster Cluster_S_V_Cluster { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cluster_S_V_Cluster
    {
        [XmlElement("U8")]
        public List<U8> U8 { get; set; }
    }

    public class U8
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Val { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the inner Cluster Node is encoded.
if you cant have it decoded in that file on the first place (when saving the file), just add:

```
 xml = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(xml);
```

after :

```
 var xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.xml");
```

your main should end up looking like this:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var xml = File.ReadAllText(@"test.xml");
        xml = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(xml);
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Cluster));

        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var info = (Cluster)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: I got an "invalid operation exception" on the line "var info = ..."

Error is:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Comment: I tried this several times.
the code I have posted should work.
what do you get after "HtmlDecode"? do you get a valid XML if you wish see it in the debugger?
can you post your original XML file? and the full exception (also inner exception)?

Comment: My XML text file is a big file. Its has everything XML decoded except the part above where it still has XML encoded. Per your question, right after the  HtmlDecoder the XML string contains some invalid contents like this "The XML page cannot be displayed 

Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Whitespace is not allowed at this location. Error processing resource 'file
"

Comment: seems like mal formatted xml, are you sure it is a valid XML? can you try open the file "test.xml" in a browser?

Comment: I have many different XML files of the same kind but for different Object; I notice that whenever the file has "<DBL>
  <Name>Duration</Name> 
  <Val /> 
  </DBL>" then the system crashed using the HTMLDecode. If you look at the "<Val />" do you think that could cause the problem? Because normally I would have "<Val>....and followed by a closing </Val>".

Comment: I am sure it is not the issue.
just tried it and it works fine.
try opening it in a browser it would tell you the problematic line.